Add a word in special place in string
I have a table contain list of queries and I want to add db link to end of source tables list. For example I have
> Select * from s1.table t1,s2.table2 ,s3.table3;

And I want to convert it to
> Select * from s1.table@dblink t1,s2.table2@dblink ,s3.table3@dblink;

All tables have schema name.
Some of tables have alias name but another haven't.
Thanks to all of you if can give me a hint

There's no question here.

My question is simple how to add  a db link to all of table names in queries .

Then you need to clarify that those queries are quoted strings and your question is how to change a string into another string. That's not normally how we work with queries so you need to be explicit or folks are you going to miss your intention.

If that stored query looks as you said, then you could use regular expression and do the replace (see ID = 1 in the following example, which results in what you want).
However, as such a regular expression affects any combination of a "word followed by a dot followed by a word" (which is (\w+)(\.)(\w+)), include from so that it wouldn't add database link name to e.g. ID = 2 "table_alias.column_name" (t1.name) as well.
SQL> with test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'Select * from s1.table t1,s2.table2 ,s3.table3;'   from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'select t1.name, t2.* from s1.table t1, s2.table2;' from dual)
  4  select id,
  5    regexp_replace(col, 'from (\w+)(\.)(\w+)', 'from \1\2\3@dblink') result
  6  from test;

        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Select * from s1.table@dblink t1,s2.table2 ,s3.table3;
         2 select t1.name, t2.* from s1.table@dblink t1, s2.table2;

SQL>

Certainly, there can be numerous combinations which might produce wrong result (split lines, additional spaces, subqueries, inline views and more).
Therefore, a few more suggestions:

how many rows are there? If not that many, add database link manually
create synonyms for all tables you'd access over the database link. Doing so, you won't have to modified stored queries

that won't work if current schema already contains objects whose name are the same as tables' names you query over the database link




If you are storing queries as strings in a table and then intend to execute them dynamically, and there is need to make changes to them before doing so, I suggest you implement your own system of placeholders and replace those placeholders at execute time. Basically, create your own pre-compiler. For example, store this in your table:
Select * from s1.table::DBLINK:: t1,s2.table2::DBLINK:: ,s3.table3::DBLINK::

Then when you need to execute it, programmatically replace ::DBLINK:: with whatever you want. You could of course use any system of marking you can come up with. In PL/SQL you have control of how you replace these to render valid SQL. Conditionally, if no dblink is needed, then replace it with an empty string, otherwise the @dblink needed:
DECLARE
  var_query varchar2(4000);
  var_dblink varchar2(129);
BEGIN
  var_dblink := '@dblink';

  SELECT REPLACE(query_text,'::DBLINK::',var_dblink)
    INTO var_query
    FROM querytable
   WHERE query_id = 1234;

  -- now execute var_query however makes the most sense for your app
END;

This is far easier and safer than trying to parse SQL to find table references, which can be immeasurably more complicated in some queries than the simplistic example you provided. Oracle's parsing engine can do that, but you don't want to try to reinvent that.
The same technique can be used to change or add hints, disable clauses (simply delimit them before and after with something that can be easily found and that never occurs in the query itself), add columns, or really any other change you might need to make.

Thank you for good answer but how can I add placeholders to end of my tables. You must cover all states of table names in a query like join of many queries , sub queries cross joins and so on. I want a regexp to cover all of these states

@MahdiFaramarzi, you store the queries that way in the first place. You're not going to get a regexp to splice them in after the fact, it's far too complicated. You need to start with SQL with placeholders stored in the physical table, then you replace those placeholders (or remove them) at execute time.
